# 301 redirect not working in IIS 7

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I need to create this 301 redirect rule:
`/blog/item.asp?n=12817` redirect to `/blog/item/12817`

I created a rule in IIS URL Rewrite module with these parameters :

Pattern: `^blog/item.asp\?n=([0-9]+)`

redirect url: `blog/item/{R:1}`

When I test it in IIS it works fine and it created this rule in my web.config:

```
<rule name="Asp classic Legacy 301 redirect" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^blog/item.asp\?n=([0-9]+)" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="blog/item/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

But still when I navigate to `/blog/item.asp?n=12817` in browser it shows me `The resource cannot be found.` error with text `Requested URL: /blog/item.asp`

Why can it be? Do I need to switch something else somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I created another rule which works:

```
<rule name="Asp classic legacy 301 redirect">  
  <match url="blog/item\.asp$" />  
    <conditions>  
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="n=(\d+)" />  
    </conditions>  
    <action type="Redirect" url="blog/item/{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>  
</rule>
```

Still wondering why would Url rewriting module generates rules which don't work?