# IIS Web.Config 301 Redirect on Query String Parameter (?)

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

```
    <rule name="blog" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="en/blog.aspx?Id=9" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mynewurl.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

I can redirect "en/blog.aspx" but I am unable to redirect only "en/blog.aspx?Id=9".

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that your 'match' is not matching en/blog.aspx?Id=9, or are you saying you are unable to redirect to it in your action?

Comment: The match is not working with query parameters

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

/en/blog.aspx?Id=9 will redirect to http://www.newurl.com.

```
    <rule name="blog" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="en/blog.aspx$" />
      <conditions>  
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="Id=9" />  
    </conditions>  
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newurl.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Found the solution here : [301 redirect not working in IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833259/301-redirect-not-working-in-iis-7)

Comment: And for anyone interested in some reading on this topic, see: [IIS URL Rewriting and ASP.NET Routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/)