# Web.Config Url rewrite works but Redirect not working

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-10

I have the following web.config Where I have added the URL Rewrite and redirect rules. Which is partially working.

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <caching enabled="false" />
        
        <rewrite>
        
          <rules>
          
              
            <rule name="Rewrite to pages.asp">
              <match url="^pages/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="pages.asp?p={R:1}" />
            </rule>
            
            <rule name="Redirect from pages.asp">
                <match url="^pages/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="pages/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
            
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**The URL structure is like this:**

```
https://www.example.com/pages.asp?p=my-article
```

**The rewrite should be like this (and it works):**

```
https://www.example.com/pages/my-article/
```

if I manually visit this URL it works but the redirect part is not working as it should automatically. Something is wrong with this code.

Comment: Are you getting an error such as "This page is not redirecting properly"? If so, it may be due to an infinite redirect loop. Consider adding `stopProcessing="true"` to the rewrite rule to prevent the redirect rule from being applied (again).

Comment: Why do you need that redirect rule? Explain please what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: @FlorianWinter I'm not getting this sort of error. But I have added this parameter to be on the safe side.

Comment: @LexLi Actually there are a lot of pages in the application (indexed by Google) therefore I want them to redirect. I have tried the Inbound/Outbound rules but I can't understand them properly.

Comment: If your goal is to redirect old links (like `pages.asp?p=my-article`) to the extensionless version, then you were writing a completely wrong redirect rule (as you tried to match the wrong thing).

Comment: yes, my goal is that.

Comment: @LexLi is right. Both rules have the same regex ("match"), but the redirect rule must be changed to instead match the "pages.asp" URLs. However, you also have to catch the query string parameter and use it in the action, which is more complicated. This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11039264/2279059

Comment: You may also want to consider adding an outbound rule which rewrites any URLs returned by requests, which may be in the "old" format. In general, I would recommend reading the documentation of URL rewriting in IIS: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules were all written wrong, by using the IIS rewrite rule manager, I have a working code now. This might help someone else with the same issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <caching enabled="false" />
        
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                
                <rule name="RedirectPages" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^pages\.asp$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^p=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="pages/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewritePages" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^pages/([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="pages.asp?p={R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="OutboundPages" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^(.*/)pages\.asp\?p=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}pages/{R:2}/" />
                </rule>
                
            </outboundRules>
          
          
        </rewrite>
            
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The execution order of url rewrite rule is from top to bottom, after executing the Rewrite rule, the rewritten URL does not match the parameters in your redirection rule, which is why the redirection does not work.

For more detailed error information, you can use failed request tracking to view.

[Using Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules)

Comment: I think the intention is that the ".asp" URL should redirect to the "RESTfull" URL, and the "RESTfull" URL should rewrite to the ".asp" URL. The rewrite rule does not match an ".asp" URL, so I think it cannot be the reason the redirect does not work. But maybe I am missing something...