# Redirect with 301 Permamnent redirect does not send url parameters

Tags: asp.net, redirect

My site was http://tebim.ir .

I decided to create a new domain and move my site there without loosing my google ranking. Google change address tool told me to do 301 redirect to my new domain and I did so.

Now redirect works fine but my url parameters(query strings) are not sent with redirect.

for example browsing www.old-domain.com/view.aspx?id=5047 redirects to www.new-domain.com/view.aspx.

?id=5047 is removed.

** I redirected my site using WebSitePanel CPanel. here is the picture of the redirect form:

[image]
what is wrong? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the URl Rewrite

```
 <rule name="behdoctor" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="tebim.ir$" />
      <conditions>  
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="Id=5047" />  
    </conditions>  
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newdomain.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

For More Info Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833259/301-redirect-not-working-in-iis-7) link

Comment: Where should i write this? project is asp.net webforms.

Comment: @Ali.Rashidi in Web Config

Comment: thank you, but it didn't work. no redirection happens.